# Listing files from static resources from different module

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have got two different modules - `A` and `B`- running on two different ports in my `spring boot + gradle + kotlin` app. Inside the module `A` resources folder, I have got some txt files inside `test-data/static/files/*` directory.

The `application.properties` file from module `A` looks like this:

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/test-data/static
```

Here is my service from module `B` that reads static files from the module `A`

```kotlin
@Service
class ResourcesProviderService(private val resourceLoader: ResourceLoader) {

    fun getResource(filename: String): Resource =
        return resourceLoader.getResource("http://localhost:8181/$filename")
    
}
```

The service can read single files when I provide the `files/files1.txt` as a `filename` parameter for example.
However, in my module `B`, I want to get names of all files from the `test-data/static/files`.
I tried to use the `ResourcePatternResolver` but it returns empty list

```kotlin
fun getAllResources(): Array<Resource> = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("http://localhost:8181/files/**")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "list all files" ... as html or json? please be more specific! ..but thinking of html this is exactly the (long forgotten, discouraged, insecure, disabled by default) "listings" feature of (tomcat's) default servlet.. (which in turn is spring-boot-web's default web container:)

Comment: I just need names of all files from given directory. I am trying to use the `ResourcePatternResolver` now but it does not work
`fun getAllResources(): Array<Resource> = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("http://localhost:8181/files/**")`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a (good ole) "ftp server"...

(Static resources nowadays best/normally reside in "Cloud buckets"...)

For a "REST-solution", I would recommend you to implement a custom!

But to activate Tomcat's ([default servlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/default-servlet.html)) "listings" feature:

- shows directory listing, when no "welcome file" is in the folder
- looks like:

  [image: browser screenshot]

...,we can "misuse springboot as an embedded tomcat starter".

*Deactivating spring DispatchServlet* and (effectively) all of spring-web (leaving only the "spring-boot" and "embedded-server" "parts") :

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

For a quick sample we put our "static structure" under ***`src/main/webapp`***:

```text
./
foo/ <-- folder (with content, structure...)
bar/ <-- folder
baz/ <-- folder
README.md <-- file
```

Then (only) add this bean:

```java
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Wrapper;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer;
// ...
@Bean
TomcatContextCustomizer tommyCustom() {
    return (Context context) -> {
        Wrapper defaultServlet = context.createWrapper();
        defaultServlet.setName("default");
        defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
        defaultServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0"); // experiment..
        defaultServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "true"); // we want this!
        defaultServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        defaultServlet.setOverridable(true);
        context.addChild(defaultServlet);
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/", "default");
    };
}
```

(this is wrap/copied from [springboot tomcat auto configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java#L286-L297), adjusting init parameter "listings")

After a `mvn package` ,since it maps our src/main/webapp to "context root", this already "runs from IDE".

To create a runnable war/jar archive, we could use maven standard (jar,war,...) plugins or the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

To enable external locations, this is sufficient with above setup:

```java
@Bean
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tommyFactoryCustom(
        @Value("${my.path-to-static-rss:${user.home}/webapp}") FileSystemResource docBase) {
    return fact -> fact.setDocumentRoot(docBase.getFile());
}
```

. ([4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java#L221))

This is a forgotten (deactivated by default), discouraged, "dangerous" feature, but still exists ... and probably also (similar) in other containers.

---

#### A Dynamic REST solution

..can look like this (sorry, it's all in java..)

1. (cleanup) We enable back DispatchServlet (+addendum)
2. (cleanup) Remove Tomcat specific beans.
3. Set (to be clear):

   ```properties
   spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:///${user.home}/webapp
   spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
   ```

Then our controller can look like (see comments):

```java
@Controller
static class StaticRssDirectoryController {
    @Autowired
    WebProperties webProps; // <- spring boot "spring.web.*" properties
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader rssLoader; // <- spring.core.io

    @GetMapping("/dynamic")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> dymanic(
            /*
                * we could have done this with a "path variable", but then need one variable
                * per path level ... ;(
                * So: We only need to care about size (256bytes ?) and (url) encoding (crazy
                * characters/paths/mallicious injection...)
                */
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String q)
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        return listFilesOrRedirectOrNotFound(q);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<List<String>> listFilesOrRedirectOrNotFound(String path)
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        List<String> fNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String loc : webProps.getResources().getStaticLocations()) { // consider all locations
            Resource rssLoc = rssLoader.getResource(loc + "/" + path);
            File fsFile = rssLoc.getFile(); // <- throws (declared) exception
            if (fsFile.exists()) { // file exists
                if (fsFile.isDirectory()) { // it's a directory:
                    File[] children = fsFile.listFiles(/* filter WEB-INF, META-INF? */);
                    for (File f : children) {
                        fNames.add(f.getName()); // only the plain file names in a list<string>
                    }
                } else { // it's a (found) file, we redirect to "spring default static handler"
                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setLocation(
                      new URI( // <- this throws (declared) exception
                        "/static/" + path /* <- this should align with spring.mvc.static-path-pattern */
                       )
                    ); 
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND); // <- sends redirect
                }
            }
        }
        return fNames.isEmpty() ? new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) // nothing found
                : ResponseEntity.ok(fNames); // or names
    }
}
```

To access it like:

```bash
# list root:
>curl http://localhost:8080/dynamic
["bar","baz","foo","README.md","WEB-INF"]
# list sub-dir:
>curl http://localhost:8080/dynamic?q=foo  
["BOOT-INF","META-INF","WEB-INF","World.txt"]
# show headers:
>curl -i http://localhost:8080/dynamic?q=foo/World.txt
HTTP/1.1 302 
Location: /static/foo/World.txt
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 19:21:48 GMT
# or follow redirects:
>curl -L http://localhost:8080/dynamic?q=foo/World.txt
World
```